# Making reversed output using vector, stl

Tags: c++, stl

I read data from a text file named `test.txt`. File contents:

> C++ is disturbing me every day

and i want a result like,

1. ++C si gnibrutsid yreve yad   (reversed words)
2. is me C++ day every disturbing  (sorted based on length)

How can I do it? Here's what I have tried:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namesapce std;

string file { "test.txt" }

int main()

{
  ifstream in(file);

  vector<char> v{istreambuc_iterator<char>(in), istreambuf_iterator < char()};

  /* my horrible coding
  int n{ 0 };
      for (auto i = v.cbegin(); i < v.cend(); ++i)
      {
              int tmp=0;
              if (*i == ' ')
              {
                      v[n] = tmp;
                      v[n] = *i;
                      tmp = *i;
              }n++;

      }
  --------------------*/
  for (auto c : v) cout << c;
}
```

Comment: I would split the line by spaces into a vector of strings. Then I would revert the strings or sort the vector

Comment: comments do nothing. When showing your attempt you better show code together with its output, not just a big block comment.

Comment: Did you retype your code? It's full of typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C++ build in algorithms.

First see the example code, which could give you and idea on how it could be implemented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string fileName{ "test.txt" };

int main() {

    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened.
    if (std::ifstream inStream(fileName); inStream) {

        // Read all words from the file into our vector
        std::vector words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(inStream), {});

        std::cout << "\nReversed words:\n\n";
        // Show reversed words
        std::transform(words.begin(), words.end(),  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "), 
            [](const std::string& s) { return std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()); });

        // Sort
        std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());

        // Show sorted list of words
        std::cout << "\n\n\nSorted list of words:\n\n";
        std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open file: " << fileName << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First, we open the file and check, if open was successful. This we do with the [if with init statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). So we prevent pollution of the outer namespace. The stream variable is just used within the `if`-statement. And by using the init part of the `if`-statement, we will open the file. The condition part of the `if`-statement is just the stream variable. And this will work, because the [bool operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) of the ios::stream is overloaded and will return, if the file stream is ok or not.

OK, now the file is open, and we wan to read all words. So, we define a `std::vector` named "words". There is no need to define the template parameter of the `std::vector`. With C++17 CTAD (Class Template Argument Deduction), because it will be deduced automatically.

We use the range constructor of the [std::vector (here number 5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). The `begin` iterator is the [std::istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). It will call the extractor operator >> until all input is consumed. Please note. We do not need to explicitly mention the `end` iterator, since the {} will be used as default initializer. Please see here: [constructor number 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator).

So, be defining the variable and using its range constructor, we will read all words from the file.

For reversing the words, we will also use the range constructor of the `std::sting`. And as `begin` and `end` iterator we use the reversed versions. So, very simple.

And to show the reversed strings, we will use `std::transform`, go over all words, put it into the `std::ostream_operator`. This will call the inserter operator << for all words. And the transformation function is a Lambda, that returns the reversed string.

Sorting is trivial and also copying the sorted words to `std::cout` is rather simple.

All this results in elegant and modern C++ code, with only a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

Read each word individually, and then do whatever processing you want:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

void printReversedWords(std::vector<std::string> const& vec) noexcept {
        for (auto const& str : vec) {
                std::copy(str.crbegin(), str.crend(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
                std::cout << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
}

// remove noexcept if you care catching bad_alloc
void printSortedVec(std::vector<std::string> const& vec) noexcept {
        auto const vec_view = [&vec] {
                std::vector<std::string const*> vec_view;
                vec_view.reserve(vec.size());

                std::transform(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), std::back_inserter(vec_view),
                        [](auto const& str) { return &str; });

                std::sort(vec_view.begin(), vec_view.end(),
                        [](auto const* const pstr1, auto const* const pstr2) {
                                return pstr1->size() < pstr2->size();
                        });
                return vec_view;
        }(); // IILE


        for (auto const* const pstr : vec_view) std::cout << *pstr << ' ';

        std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
        auto constexpr fileName = "./test.txt";
        std::ifstream in(fileName);

        if (!in) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to open the file";
                return -1;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> const vec{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in), {} };
        printReversedWords(vec);
        printSortedVec(vec);
}
```

Comment: I would probably have used  "for (auto str: vec) { std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); std::out << str << ' '; }", but I don't think any of the two solutions is inherently better. One is a bit more explicit, the other probably a bit faster. BTW, the sorting is based on word length.

Comment: @stefaanv I agree with your statement. I would also say it's a matter of style, perhaps? Thank you for the feedback about sorting rules.